# vertical-text sidebar with position:fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
       div.row {position: fixed;}
              
              
        
        #vertical {

            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);   
            -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);

                  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                  <p id="testo">
                    Cor is an Italian artist based in Belgium.<br>
                    Cor is both analogic and digital<br>
                    Cor looks towards vernacular, surrealist<br>
                    and pop culture.<br>
                 </p>
           </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-2" id="vertical"> 
      
                    <a class="contact" href="#">Instagram   </a>         
                    <a class="contact" href="#">Email   </a>                       
                    <a class="contact" href="#">Credits   </a>
           
           </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

i'm tryng to insert in a bootstrap container (containing only text with position:fixed) a vertical-text rotated list of contacts ( like email, instagram ecc) that must be at the right edge of the screen (inside the container, so with position:fixed as well) but i'm have troubles with the positioning , could you help?

Comment: sorry, i had problems providing code

Comment: So you want the left side to also be fixed? Also, if its aligned to the side of container, that doesn't always mean its the edge of the screen.

Comment: i want something like this http://jsbin.com/ravuduni/2

Comment: but to the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Imvain2, I moved your vertical text out of the container; in fact, Bootstrap may not be necessary here.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
              <p id="testo">
                Cor is an Italian artist based in Belgium.<br>
                Cor is both analogic and digital<br>
                Cor looks towards vernacular, surrealist<br>
                and pop culture.<br>
             </p>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="vertical"> 
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="contact" href="#">Instagram</a>
    <a class="contact" href="#">Email</a>
    <a class="contact" href="#">Credits</a>
  </div>      
</div>
```

I also styled your vertical text a little more, so that it's flush to the right of the viewport. Most importantly, the wrapper for the vertical text has to have a *width* of *100vh*, since it's being rotated.

```
#vertical {
  position: fixed;
  background-color:#cccccc;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 48px);
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, -15px);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  width: 100vh;
}
```

See [the pen](https://codepen.io/nosnetrom/pen/gyoXRy).

Comment: last question, how can i make the vertical text responsive as the one in the container?

Answer (score 0):

Your row needs to be 100% width. Add this CSS to your page:

```
.row {
width: 100%;
}

div#vertical {
position: absolute;
top: 85px;
right: -35px;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks now contacts are at the right but they are not properly formatted, credits is not under email but it collapse at the left

Comment: Okay, so you need the items to be underneath each other? Perhaps an unordered list?

Comment: well yes a list should work too, and i'm tryng to give some distance between the 3 contacts mantaining the right proportions between the text in the container and the contacs, because the whole page seems not to be very responsive at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I modified your HTML to have the side nav outside of container and fixed just that div with the vertical text.

```css
        .side-nav {
            position:fixed;
            right:0;
            top:100px;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);   
            -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            background:#c0c0c0;
                  }

.row{/*just to see nav is fixed*/
height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-nav">
                <a class="contact" href="#">Instagram   </a>         
                    <a class="contact" href="#">Email   </a>                       
                    <a class="contact" href="#">Credits   </a>
</div>


<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
                  <p id="testo">
                    Cor is an Italian artist based in Belgium.<br>
                    Cor is both analogic and digital<br>
                    Cor looks towards vernacular, surrealist<br>
                    and pop culture.</p>
  </div>

  </div>
```